# Picasso and Glide, downloading images from Dropbox

Tags: android, hosting, dropbox, picasso, android-glide

I'm creating an app and I would like to keep my images on Dropbox and keep URL to them in a database.

I tried to load a sample image https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqm2hw87sjt9pde/sample.jpg?dl=0

However, it doesn't load my image. Logcat isn't very helpful

```
05-04 22:36:50.829 30881-30881/eu.szwiec.checkittravelkit D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
05-04 22:36:50.835 30881-30886/eu.szwiec.checkittravelkit I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=83KB, data=81KB
After code cache collection, code=65KB, data=57KB
05-04 22:36:51.130 30881-30905/eu.szwiec.checkittravelkit D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7c05121800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7c0f268b80
05-04 22:36:52.046 30881-30917/eu.szwiec.checkittravelkit D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null
05-04 22:36:53.457 30881-30926/eu.szwiec.checkittravelkit D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null
```

This image is loaded without a problem https://lh6.ggpht.com/9SZhHdv4URtBzRmXpnWxZcYhkgTQurFuuQ8OR7WZ3R7fyTmha77dYkVvcuqMu3DLvMQ=w300

Can I modify my URL somehow?
If not, which image hosting works well with Picasso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

The official way to create a direct link is to first create a share link using the regular process, and then change the `?dl=0` at the end with `?dl=1`. The resulting link will be a direct download of the file you've linked. You can also change `?dl=0` to `?raw=1` if you need to embed the file (an image, for instance) in a web page.

Comment: For reference, here's the documentation for this: https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download

Answer (score 2):

I reckon we have to use dropbox api to fetch the direct urls linking the images. I have read https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#media and found out that the url you mention is not a direct link. That is why glide and Picasso cannot load the image into imageview.